# I did npm install -f which works fine. But while deploying the application to Netlify or on Vercel, build logs fail. Please suggest solution for above

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js13

I am using mui/styles, emotion/styled, emotion/react which require a react version lesser than or equal to 16.8.0 and Next.js v 13 that require React version above 18.2.0.
I did npm install -f which works fine. But while deploying the application to Netlify or on Vercel, build logs fail. Please suggest solution for above

I did npm install -f which works fine. But while deploying the application to Netlify or on Vercel, build logs fail. Please suggest solution for above

Answer (score -1):

Your packages are incompatible, regardless of whether or not you're able to force an npm install locally. Your app will not build until you either upgrade all or downgrade all. [`mui/styles` was deprecated years ago](https://mui.com/system/styles/basics/), so I would highly recommend replacing it with [`mui/system`](https://mui.com/system/getting-started/), which is compatible with React 18+.